# I am currently trying to return some data from an array displaying menu items into my search bar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to create a search bar to make it easy on my users so that they can type in the first letter of any ingredient such as "A" and it returns every ingredient item that is associated with that item. Such as "Avocado"

So far I have only created the array of ingredients . I am kind of new to coding so I am not sure how to get this filter list started.

Here's a brief explanation of my ingredient array

```
const ingredients: any = `{
  "ingredients" : [
  {
     "ingredient" : "Avocado",
      "category" : "Prepped"
      "servings" : 35
 },
 {
     "ingredient" : "Chopped Bacon",
     "category" : "No Prep",   
      "servings" : 40,
 }
    ]
```

]

My expected results are for the user to type in "a" into the search bar and ingredients from the menu will pop up such as... "Avocados", "Arugula", "Apples" etc. Please keep in mind my menu is collapsible. So how will this work?

Comment: You need to read this: [Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). As it stands, your posts are off-topic because they are too broad.

Comment: I edited it see if its better now

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage

Comment: Let me know if it does not help :)

Comment: no it didnt not i am trying to return data from an array containing menu items into my search bar

Answer (score 0):

Write filter using array.filter and  provide customer input to it.
Documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)